# How to initialize a local variable in Java only once

Tags: java, initialization, variable-assignment, final

In C++, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *init()
{
    printf("in init()\n");
}

static void func()
{
    static const char *str = init();
    printf("in func()\n");
}

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

shows that the despite the numerous invokations of the *func()*, *str* is only initialized once by printing a trace message in the function *init()* used to initialize *str*.  When run, there are a total of 10 lines of trace, once for *init()* and 10 times for *func()*

In Java, shouldn't the following code do the same thing?

```
class test {
    private String init()
    {
        System.out.println("in init()");
        return "FOO";
    }

    private void func()
    {
        final String str = init();
        System.out.println("in func()");
    }

    public test()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            func();
        }
    }

    public static main(String[] args)
    {
        test app = new test();
    }
}
```

When run, there are 20 lines of output, 10 each for *init()* and *func()*.
Based on what I read about *final* variables, I thought it would behave the same way.
So I tried *static final* and it would not compile (nor just *static*)
Is there a way to do this?  I need to call a time-consuming initialization function from
several different methods in my class, so just moving the variable to class scope wouldn't work.
Further, since local variables are not automatically initialized, I cannot include an *if* test for *null* around the variable before assigning it a value.
I suppose I could create a variable at in the class scope for each method in my class, but
managing it would be a pain to manage.
The best analogy would be something if I were to include something like the following in every method:

```
public myfunc1()
{
    final String funcName = java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
}
public myfunc2()
{
    final String funcName = java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
}
```

*funcName* in this case will get a unique value in each method, but the initialization is expensive.

Comment: You need boft the string str and function init() be static

Comment: _str_ cannot be _static_, it will not compile. _init()_ cannot be _static_ since it relies on instance data.

Comment: http://ideone.com/nHN6m9

Answer (score 5):

The following is a fairly close approximation:

```
class test {

    private static final String str = init();

    private static String init()
    {
        System.out.println("in init()");
        return "FOO";
    }

    private void func()
    {
        System.out.println("in func()");
    }

    public test()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            func();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test app = new test();
    }
}
```

Note that `str` is initialized when the class is loaded, not when `func()` is called for the first time.

Comment: And if `init()` actually needs context, members which aren't initialized until class construction or later, initialize `str` to null and have `init()` only do its long thing `if (str == null)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not provide the answer, which is why I provided the further examples or _myfunc1() and _myfunc2()_ at the end of my question.

Answer (score 2):

The `final` qualifier makes the variable constant through a single method call.

Since you want a single value per instance, you can use an instance member variable, outside the method.

```
private final String str = init();

private void func()
{
    System.out.println("in func()");
}
```

If you wanted a single value across all method calls for all instances, you could use a static member variable, outside the method.

```
private static final String str = init();

private void func()
{
    System.out.println("in func()");
}
```

Comment: Not the question, single initialization call for  each multiple invoked member function.  See the example at the end: _myfunc1()_ and _myfunc2()_

Comment: You can do that with instance members too - just use a different instance member for each method that in C you'd use a static local variable.

Comment: I know that, as stated in the question, I was looking for an easier to manage solution rather creating an instance variable for every method in my class.

Comment: There's not a lot to manage. The primary difference from C/C++ is its *location* (and the choice of whether it's per instance or per class). If you prefer, you can place the member fields just before each method.